# Not able to access multiple services from ingress controller hosted on different ports

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have two services hosted on different ports and I have created a ingress resource which looks like this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /svc1/
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-svc
          servicePort: 3000
       - path: /svc2/
         backend:
           serviceName: app2-svc
           servicePort: 8080
```

on top of this I have created a ***NodePort*** type ingress controller.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
  name: controller-nginx-ingress-controller
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.88.18.191
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30080
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    nodePort: 31442
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
    component: controller
    release: controller
```

And finally, setup a cloud load balancer to access application running on my K8S cluster.

**Problem:**
I couldn't able to access any of my application using URL routing

- http://load-balancer-ip/svc1/
- http://load-balancer-ip/svc2/

Can anyone please let me know what incorrect I'm doing? And how to resolve this issue?

Comment: could you please share service manifests of relevant services that are running on port 3000 and 8080?  or double-check both service and ingress manifests. make sure the service name and port are matching.

Comment: If I mapped the svc1 or svc2 to root, then I have able to access the my application individually. e.g. - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-svc
          servicePort: 3000
       - path: /svc2/
         backend:
           serviceName: app2-svc
           servicePort: 8080                                                                                               In this case I can able to access app1 by http://<lb-ip> but not able to access app2(http://<lb-ip>/app2-svc) and vice-versa.

Comment: Are you receiving 404? Try  /svc1 and /svc2 instead of /svc1/ and /svc2/ Double-check route paths in your application code.

Comment: yes, I'm receiving 404 error. Tried, still same error i.e. 404

Comment: Most probably you need to use rewrite, take a look [here for user-guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite) and [here for example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)

Answer (score 2):

From what you mentioned in comments I am pretty sure the problem can be solved with path rewrites.

Now, when you are sending a request to `/svc1/` with `path: /svc1/` then the request is forwarded to `app1-svc` with path set to `/svc1/` and you are receiving 404 errors as there is no such path in app1. From what you mentioned, you can most probably solve the issue using rewrite. You can achieve it using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation, so your ingress would look like following:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /svc1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-svc
          servicePort: 3000
       - path: /svc2(/|$)(.*)
         backend:
           serviceName: app2-svc
           servicePort: 8080
```

In this case when sending request with path set to `/svc1/something` the request will be forwarded to app1 with path rewritten to `/something`.

Also take a look in [ingress docs for more explanation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).

Let me know if it solved you issue.